# Dynamic styles with bootstrap and css modules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a React project that is using CSS modules (for components) + React-Bootstrap with CDN-hosted CSS.

I have a requirement that when my app loads (per user), I make a call to an endpoint to get a dynamic style guide.
For simplicity, it would be something like this:

`{
  "color_background": "#edeae3",
  "color_error": "#9e2d2d",
  "color_highlight": "#69b5ce",
  "color_success": "#498e49",
}`

The app should then be rendered in those colors. I know there is the ability to customize static Bootstrap styling (e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), but I'm not sure how to do it dynamically.

Any guidance would be appreciated.